# Cannot delete desktop.ini and albumart.jpg files from command prompt

Tags: cmd

I know that it is stupid but I cannot delete certain files from command prompt (desktop.ini and albumart.jpg's):

C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\music>del desktop.ini

```
Could Not Find C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\music\desktop.ini
```

but

C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\music>dir /a desk*.*

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ****

 Directory of C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\music

02.08.2007  13:48               358 desktop.ini

           1 File(s)            358 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  151 366 811 648 bytes free
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file marked at hidden? What is the output of `attrib C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\music\desktop.ini`?

Comment: Yeah, its "A H". How to delete it without changing the attribute? Or do I have to change it?

Comment: Got it: del /A:H desktop.ini

Comment: In this case, there's no need to specify the hidden attribute, using `/A` alone should be sufficient. The `/A` option with no specified attributes, chooses them all. `Del /A "%UserProfile%\Desktop\music\desktop.ini"`

Comment: `del` without any option ignores files with hidden attributes as `/A-H` is the implicit default and does not delete files with read-only attribute set. `del /A /F /Q "%UserProfile%\Desktop\music"` deletes really all files in specified directory although the file `desktop.ini` is a very special file and should not be deleted in the user's main __music__ directory.